# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' from merging DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple code for merging two DataFrames. `df1` has 23590 rows and 4 columns and `df2` 7725 rows and 4 columns. The point is to bring them to the same dimensions for further processing. However, while the code used to work for other DataFrames, it now resolves in `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`.

The code I use is:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I never used '<' and all columns of the DataFrames have the datatype 'float64'.

While searching for an answer I saw many similar questions with the same Error message but all of them involved using the symbol '<' or different datatypes.

Comment: You specify the merge is on the Index, so the columns don't matter, it's the index comparison that is likely breaking things. What are `df1.index.dtype` and `df2.index.dtype`?

Comment: Both are datatype object. Maybe it is helpful to know, that ```df1``` has three and ```df2``` has two indices.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what the data is like? I just made 2 dfs that mimic your description (except for the number of rows) and merged them without a problem. Is there any chance the data or dfs don't match exactly with your description and there is some characteristic you aren't aware of?

Comment: Well, the data contains area values in ha between 0 ha and over 100000 ha. The three indices of ```df1``` are identifiers of river catchments, of counties and of a gridcode. ```df2```is an aggregated version of ```df1``` without the gridcode index

Comment: Hm, it might be worth going and checking into what ALollz said and actually see what the the type of the indexes that are being compared are. I can't think of another reason why that error would be coming up.

Comment: @Benno_Banton, I'm having the same problem, I know it's two years later, but did you find a solution ?